# Is there any way to make Rcpp stop defining NDEBUG?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, ndebug

[Why does assert not work here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409237/why-does-assert-not-work-here)

^ Apparently, Rcpp has a habit of defining `NDEBUG` on its own, even if not defined by myself.

```
m@m-X555LJ:~/wtfdir$ cat WTF.r
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp("WTF.cpp")
m@m-X555LJ:~/wtfdir$ cat WTF.cpp
#ifdef NDEBUG
#error WTF I did not define this
#endif
m@m-X555LJ:~/wtfdir$ ./WTF.r
WTF.cpp:2:2: error: #error WTF I did not define this
 #error WTF I did not define this
  ^~~~~
make: *** [WTF.o] Error 1
g++  -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/m/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/m/wtfdir"    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-3U0YWo/r-base-3.5.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c WTF.cpp -o WTF.o
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:172: recipe for target 'WTF.o' failed
Error in sourceCpp("WTF.cpp") : Error 1 occurred building shared library.
Execution halted
m@m-X555LJ:~/wtfdir$
```

The answers to the SO question I linked to explain that (a) It is prohibited to call `assert` in packages uploaded to CRAN, because (b) C++ code should not halt R code and (c) I should throw exceptions instead, which are caught by Rcpp.

However:

- I do not wish to upload my code to CRAN; instead, I'm writing the code for my own use;
- Even if I wished to upload it to CRAN, I could compile it myself without `NDEBUG` for testing purposes and then define `NDEBUG` just before uploading to CRAN;
- Since both R code as well as C++ code is written by myself for the same purpose (and I consider them both to be the same program), I would actually like the whole program to blow if a bug in any part of it is detected; continuing running R code if C++ code is faulty is pointless for me;
- Since I did not know `NDEBUG` would be defined, I already have put quite a few `assert`s in my code and also printing diagnostics via `std::cerr` is wrapped in `#ifndef NDEBUG`s; these fail to work obviously;
- I don't want to unconditionally throw exceptions since some `assert`s are computation heavy;
- As of now, my C++ code blows my R code anyway because it crashes, I'm trying to investigate the issue but I can't because my diagnostics don't work.

Is there any way to make Rcpp stop defining `NDEBUG`? Or am I supposed to simply remove all `asserts` and anything else that depends on `NDEBUG` and switch to throwing exceptions and stop complaining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, if you `grep` for `NDEBUG` in R's own `Makeconf` (which we can access via a convenience softlink from `/etc/R` on Debian and its derivatives due to how I set the .deb package up):

```sh
edd@rob:~$ grep NDEBUG /etc/R/Makeconf 
R_XTRA_CPPFLAGS =  -I"$(R_INCLUDE_DIR)" -DNDEBUG
ALL_CPPFLAGS =  -I"$(R_INCLUDE_DIR)" -DNDEBUG $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) $(CLINK_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)
edd@rob:~$
```

you see that it imposed by *R* rather than `Rcpp` as per your question. So your assumption was wrong.  It is under *your* local control: just edit R's `Makeconf` on *your* machine.  You just cannot automate this for hypothetical other users of your code.  But per you question, that does not appear to be an immediate concern anyway.

Second, if you want a particular `#define` you can just define it:

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void foo() {

#ifdef DEBUG
  Rcpp::Rcout << "foo: Debug mode" << std::endl;
#endif

  Rcpp::Rcout << "foo: Hello, world" << std::endl;
}

#define DEBUG 1

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void bar() {

#ifdef DEBUG
  Rcpp::Rcout << "bar: Debug mode" << std::endl;
#endif

  Rcpp::Rcout << "bar: Hello, world" << std::endl;
}


/*** R
foo()
bar()
*/
```

#### Output

```
R> sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/56209693/answer.cpp")

R> foo()
foo: Hello, world

R> bar()
bar: Debug mode
bar: Hello, world
R>
```

It is quite common to define other logging macros like `DEBUG` or `FATAL` or ... that behave like assert even if R by default (and for understandable reasons as a primarily-interactive tool) turns `assert` off.

Third and last, you can follow the approach in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24275850/143305) and temporarily undefine `NDEBUG` to include `cassert` and then redefine it.  That *will* give you `assert()` and terminate your session as I checked.  Not my approach to debug with R but hey if you really must...